# List all possible actions on a 4x4 board in Prolog

Tags: prolog

How can I list all possible boards after (for example) one player performs some action in a 4x4 board (with 8 different pions)?

The pions should be, for example:

```
([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
```

and each time you play one automatically it cannot re-used.

The board should be like this board

```
([1,1,-,-],(1,2,-,-)...(1,3,-,-)(1,4,-,-)
 [2,1,-,-],(2,2,-,-)...(2,3,-,-)(2,4,-,-)
 [3,1,-,-],(3,2,-,-)...(3,3,-,-)(3,4,-,-)
 [4,1,-,-],(4,2,-,-)...(4,3,-,-)(4,4,-,-)
```

And one player per round puts one pion on the board until it's full.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have a predicate like `board0_move_board/3`, which is a ternary relation between a board B, a move M, and the resulting board after the move M is made on B. Further, I assume you have a predicate `board_move/2` that relates a board to a move that is possible on that board, and on backtracking successively gives all moves that are possible. With these predicates, you can get all possible boards with:

```
findall(Board, (board_move(Board0, Move), board0_move_board(Board0, Move, Board)), Boards)
```

Comment: Yes i got the first predicate that you described as "board0_move_board/3"which connects a player move with the board and results the board with that move done,  but i don't have the second predicate board_move/2..at least now with the way that you describe .and also i must fill my predicate like this way "              moves((Colour,_),Board,NewBoardsList):